# Clear CSS menu hover state on click (page loaded via ajax)

Tags: jquery, css, ajax, drop-down-menu, menu

I have a CSS drop down menu on a website. Along the top there are a list of parent categories, when you hover over one, a drop down menu appears where you can then click on one of the child categories.

When you click on the child category, an ajax page load is triggered and the contents of the page are replaced. Works good.

But the problem is, because the page is not reloaded, the drop down menu is still there. You have to move the mouse off it to get it to go away. This is annoying. We want the menu to dissapear when you click on a child category. On a touch device this behaviour is even more annoying.

Rather than posting the code here, I will put a link to the website: http://tinyurl.com/blvtlwz
The menu in question is the one at the top - 'Competition Horses' 'Leisure Horses' etc.

I would be interested in any ideas of how to clear the hover state when a click is detected, or alternatively a better way of handling the menu? I have fiddled around with jquery removeClass(), but I haven't had much luck.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with this script:

```
 $(function(){
   $('#nav li').hover(function() {
     $('ul',this).show(); // this will show the hidden ul
   });
  $('#nav li ul li').click(function() {
     $(this).parent().hide().end(); // this will hide the ul
  });
});
```

Comment: This works a treat, I haven't fully tested it yet but so far it looks good :) Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could use .on instead of .click

```
// This might need some tweeking for it to work on your end
$('#nav li').on("click", function(e){
  $('#nav li').hide();
});

// When you are scrolled down a bit and click a top menu link (eg 'Competition Horses') you will "jump to top". This will prevent that.
$('#nav ul li a').on("click", function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: I like the second segment that prevents the jump back to the top - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#nav li ul li').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().fadeOut();
    return false; // comment this to allow propagaton to new page
});
$('#nav li ul li').hover(function() {
 $(this).parent().fadeIn(); 
 });
});​
```

See [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TtjDy/)

Comment: Thanks, I gave this a go but once I had clicked on the menu once it was removed and couldn't be clicked on again.