# A way to clear a :hover in a drop-down menu on a touch-screen?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a pretty standard CSS drop-down menu, using :hover to display child elements, and using the Doubletap plug-in to capture and clear touch events to allow child menu elements to be revealed on touch devices.

Now, I want to be able to "close" an opened menu item when a user taps on a cross. So far what I have is:

1. Cross is hidden by default.
2. Cross becomes visible when parent li is :hovered

But what I need is also:

1. When cross is tapped, parent :hover state is cleared (returning menu to initial state).

[Here's my JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NdU7Q/) and here's my mark-up:

```
 <ul id="main-menu">
            <li class="parent" aria-haspopup="true"><a href="#">Item One</a>
                <span class="tapclose">X</span>
                <!-- sub-menu -->
            </li>
            <li class="parent" aria-haspopup="true"><a href="#">Item Two</a>
                <span class="tapclose">X</span>
                <!-- sub-menu -->
            </li>
  </ul>
```

What's the best way to do this? The menu needs to work on both touch and mouse based interfaces. I'm open to JQuery, CSS & mark-up solutions.

Comment: I'm not where I can really answer, but we use `:hover`, `:focus`, and `:active` so you can mouse, keyboard-tab, and touch our menus.

Comment: This question has been asked before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14068773/clear-css-menu-hover-state-on-click-page-loaded-via-ajax

Answer (score 0):

> What's the best way to do this?

That's a tough question to answer because although there are several ways to achieve what you are trying to do every single approach will have its pros and cons and it will be open forever to an opinion-based debate. So I'd dare to say there is no BEST way to do it but certainly some approaches might be more suitable or cleaner

I personally think that jQuery makes everything so easy and it's nice exploring. But, by this I'm NOT claiming that is the BEST way to do it. Actually, I put together a minimalistic example that showcases its potential to deal nicely with these types of menus in this [JS Fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/t5rep/)

Where I'm using this html structure...

```
<nav>
    <div class="l1">Item 1
        <div class="l2">
           <div>Sub Item 1.1</div>
           <div>Sub Item 1.2</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="l1">Item 2 
        <div class="l2">
           <div>Sub Item 1.1</div>
           <div>Sub Item 1.2</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="l1">Item 3
        <div class="l2">
           <div>Sub Item 1.1</div>
           <div>Sub Item 1.2</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="l1">Item 4
        <div class="l2">
           <div>Sub Item 1.1</div>
           <div>Sub Item 1.2</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Consider using `ul` and `li` elements instead. I'm also using this stylesheets...

```
nav{
    display:block;
    height:25px;
    padding:10px 50px;
    background-color:black;
    color:yellow;
    font-weight:bold;
}
nav div.l1{
    margin-right:20px;
    display:inline-block;
    zoom:1;
    *display:inline;
}
nav div.l2{
    display:none;
    background-color:yellow;
    color:black;
    position:absolute;
    margin-top:16px;
    z-index:1;
    padding:20px 10px;
}
```

and finally this jQuery...

```
$(function(){
    $('div.l1').click(toggleSubItems);
});

function toggleSubItems(){
    $('div.l2').not($(this).children('div.l2')).hide();
    $(this).children('div.l2').toggle(400);
}
```

Notice that all concerns are nicely separated...javascript, html, css. But again, take this as an example to showcase its potential to be expanded not as a template for your project.

Hope it helps